# A pattern where "Variable is used before being assigned" (TS2454) is not helpful

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code pattern,

```
class stuff {
    public id: string;
    public uid: number;
    constructor(parameter: string){
        this.id = parameter;
    }
    public getUID(): number {
        return Date.now();
    }
}

let ids: number[]; /* 1: Here variable is not assigned */
for ( let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    ids[i] = new stuff(i.toString()).getUID();
    /* 2: Here ids[i] is used before initialized */
}
```

In such a pattern, typescript won't compile with `"strict": true`.

I could do `let ids:number[] | undefined` but that loses the value of using typescript.

Is there any other pattern with which I can achieve the same behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the following work? `let ids: number[] = [];` and: `ids.push(new stuff(i.toString()).getUID());`

Comment: Why are you not initializing `ids`?  The compiler is correctly warning you that you are indexing into an undefined value, which will blow up at runtime.

Comment: @HMR It does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let ids: number[] = [];
for ( let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    ids.push(new stuff(i.toString()).getUID());
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would do to this is make ids a const.